# Irreducible is Prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that this property holds for euclidean rings, PIDs, UFDs and GCD domains. But does it hold for Bezout rings, Noetherian rings or ACCP rings?

Comment: On wikipedia I just found that In [GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) irreducibles are prime. Maybe you can find answers there for the others as well. Btw, Bezout domains are GCD domains.

Answer (score 1):

In Bézout domains, irreducibles are prime.

An ACCP domain in which every irreducible is prime is a UFD, so any non-UFD noetherian domain is a counterexample for the remaining two cases.